# Solving simple inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Let $ u, V, C $ be constants. For what values of $ \theta $ is
$$
\left| \frac{\cos(u) + e^{i\theta} V \sin(u)}{ \sin(u) - e^{i\theta} V \cos(u)} \right| < C
$$

I feel like there is some nice geometric interpretation that would make the inequality easy to understand, but I'm just not seeing it! I've tried some special cases of $ V $ and $ C $, but I can't work out a general formula. Any help would be appreciated!